# Over write UI component's autoresizingmask generated by storyboard in code iOS 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios-universal-app, autoresizingmask

I am porting my iPhone app into Universal app. I am supporting only portrait mode for iPhone but for iPad only Landscape mode is supported. I want to keep my few views only autoresizable in only height for iPad whereas for iPhone its completely autoresizable.

In storyboard i have added all autoresizablemask and for iPad i am using `viewDidLoad` to override `autoresizingMask` for the view which i want to be autoresizable only in iPad as shown in below code:

```
self.view_MainBackGround.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin;
```

but its not working in iOS 8, i want to know what i am doing wrong, where should i set `autoresizingMask` for few views, which will be resizing in all direction for iPhone but only height for iPad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up setting `view_MainBackGround` frame in `viewWillAppear:` since setting frame will not work in `viewDidLoad` because when the view loads its actually in `landscape` size and changes in `portrait` mode when it appears after loading.